# @OneToOne relationship between JPA entities that don't share any foreign key relationship

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities as follows:

- `Invoice`

  - Primary Key is `InvoiceId`
  - Other columns of interest are `[OrgId, VendorId, VendorInvoiceId]`
- `InvoiceState`

  - Primary Key is `InvoiceStateId`
  - Other columns of interest are `[OrgId, VendorId, VendorInvoiceId]`

The "other columns of interest" form a unique key in both the tables, except that the second table, `InvoiceState`, can contain records that doesn't have a corresponding record in the first table, `Invoice`.

At the entity layer, I would like define `Invoice` entity to contain a reference to `InvoiceState` entity with a `@OneToOne` relationship defined, with `@JoinColumns` as follows:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns
({
    @JoinColumn(name="OrgId", referencedColumnName="OrgId"),
    @JoinColumn(name="VendorId", referencedColumnName="VendorId"),
    @JoinColumn(name="VendorInvoiceId", referencedColumnName="VendorInvoiceId")
})
```

But this throws an exception that the foreign key count is not the same in both entities. I don't even have a foreign key defined between these two tables.

Is there a way to define a `@OneToOne` relationship between two entities that don't share Foreign Keys, but have a set of column that can be used during `JOIN`?

Comment: The name of an "entity" really ought to be a noun to be more understandable, hence Invoice and InvoiceState ... fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to map the above 3 columns as a `component` using `@Embeddable` and use the component in for mapping using `@Embedded` and defining the joining condition.

e.g. below:

```
  @Embeddable
  public class ReferenceInfo {

      private Long orgId = null;
      private Long vendorId= null;
      private Long vendorInvoiceId= null;

      .........
      .........
  }


  @Entity
  public class Invoces{

     private Long invoiceId = null;
     private ReferenceInfo refInfo = null;
     private InvoiceStates invoiceStates = null;

     @Id
     public Long getInvoiceId(){
        return invoiceId;
     }

     ......

      @Embedded
      public ReferenceInfo getRefInfo(){
        ....
      }

      @OneToOne(mappedBy="refInfo"))
      public InvoiceStates getInvoiceStates(){
        return invoiceStates;
      }
  }


  @Entity
  public class InvoiceStates {

     private Long invoiceStateId = null;
     private ReferenceInfo refInfo = null;

     @Id
     public Long getInvoiceStateId(){
        return invoiceStateId;
     }

     ......

      @Embedded
      public ReferenceInfo getRefInfo(){
        ....
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the three fields are unique, you can mark them as the PK for the InvoicesState entity, which then allows state to reference them in a oneToOne.  The PK used for JPA doesnt need to match the table id, it just needs to be unique.

Some providers do allow referencing non-PK fields in mappings.   This isn't always suggested though because the entities are usually cached on PKs, so you may get extra database hits to resolve the reference.  In Eclipselink, you could fake the mapping out by using only one of the fields, and correct the mapping in a descriptor customizer to add the remaining fields in the relationship.

Comment: These tables are currently quite large and also have a lot of history as to how they evolved and such changes at the DB layer require a lot of investigation and hence was looking for some solution to still define a proper one-to-one at the domain layer.

Comment: Marking the 3 columns as the ID in JPA doesn't change anything in the database, and allows you to use proper one to ones.